# Java Optional: how to do with long map() chain

Tags: java, option-type

Recently, I started using Optional when handling json response in our project:

```
Optional.ofNullable(root.get("a"))
        .map(a -> a.get("b"))
        .map(b -> b.get("c"))
        .map(c -> c.get("d"))
```

for each get(), I have to use a map() to keep the return value in the "safety box" which makes the code quite verbose. To access a very deep json field in a complex long json tree, it would end up with a quite long map() chain.

I was dreaming of something like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(root.get("a")).map(a.get("b").get("c").get("d"))
```

If any of those get() methods returns a null value, I would get an empty Optional as result of the expression. Let's say, using one "safety box", all possible null values can be somehow handled and turned into empty Optional. Is it a silly thought?

Is there a way to make the code less-verbose?

Comment: You can use `&&` inside `map`.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it up inside a method:

```
static Optional<JsonObject> get(JsonObject root, String... paths) {
  Optional<JsonObject> opt = Optional.ofNullable(root);
  for (String p : paths) {
    if (!opt.isPresent()) break;
    opt = opt.map(a -> a.get(p));
  }
  return opt;
}
```

then call like:

```
Optional<JsonObject> jsonObject = get(root, "a", "b", "c", "d");
```

Comment: Op asked: `Is there a way to make the code less-verbose?`

Comment: Wouldn't it make a little more sense for the `isPresent()` check to be a line earlier?

Comment: @CommonMan Is this answer not less-verbose? It's reusable and can be used for an arbitrarily large `paths` array. It effectively turns all the `map(...)` calls into a simple varargs parameter.

Comment: @Slaw , i think verbose has something to do with less or more code.

Comment: @CommonMan No, it hasn't. Or OP prefers to have his/her own definition of common words.

Comment: @Tom, thanks man, i will have to do some google now. It is always better to get things right than keep misconception. Thanks everyone for the nudge. +1

Comment: @CommonMan But I agree with you that this answer is not that good. OPs issue is that the method, which wants to access "d", needs to know the structure of where to get it, thus being verbose in regard of which "way" to go to reach "d". This also duplicates the information of the JSON structure on multiple places in the code. A much better solution would provide a getter like `getD(root)`and it internally know how to get "d".

Comment: @Tom Just stumbled upon this: ( It is correct?? ) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141175/why-is-verbosity-bad-for-a-programming-language

Comment: @Tom And internally it might use this answer, as there might be many methods like `getD(root)`, all implemented similarly; I think this option minimizes code duplication in such cases, though I would tend to agree it's better as an implementation detail.

Comment: @CommonMan I guess so. So you weren't wrong with your remake in the first comment.

Comment: @CommonMan the point of pulling stuff out into a method is that you pay the cost of verbosity once in defining the method, and then have much lower verbosity for every subsequent invocation that you add. The marginal verbosity, if you like, is reduced by defining such a method, even if the initial verbosity outlay is comparable or greater.

Comment: @Slaw If you have "many methods like `getD(root)`", then you're doing it wrong. There should be only one such method implementation and optimally in one class with the other getters of that JSON structure, so only one class needs to know how the JSON is structured and other methods can easily access certain data without knowing where from the JSON it is coming from.

Comment: @AndyTurner , I will confess that i have learnt many things from you  by seeing your answers, i made my 1st comment just seeing the lines of code, i suspect nothing less in your answer as i am still learning. I find it good to interact with reputed members like you. Hope you can understand.

Comment: @Tom That's what I mean by "many methods like `getD(root)`"... The point is that this one class would use this method internally for all the similar methods.

Comment: @khelwood "a line earlier" yeah, that makes sense. Edited.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks man, I really like your idea. When trying to apply your approach, I found out that I also have to handle array nodes (sorry for not mentioning this point in the question). But passing the indexes as parameter would not be good. any idea?

Comment: @wanxg that makes it substantially more complicated. Perhaps you should look for a library that allows you to express arbitrary paths into the JSON, for example [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) (mentioned with no recommendation whatsoever; merely that is one example).